# Соотнести данные из одного столбца к другому

Tags: windows, excel

На листе1 указаны техкарты, а на листе2 привязанные к техкартам МО (малоценный инвентарь)
На листе2 указаны позиции с техкартами, которых нет на листе1
Нужно вывести список МО на листе2 только по тем техкартам, которые указаны на листе1
Возможно надо сравнить два столбца и выделить или вывести формулой на отдельную страницу все строки из листа2, по которым есть совпадения с листом1
Соотнести MEDUSL из листа2 к MEDUSL листа1[image: Лист1]

[image: Лист2]

Comment: Добавьте на лист 2 столбец, который `ВПР()`-ит MEDUSL с листа 1, и включите фильтр по непустому значению. Ну или сразу фильтр по формуле.

Comment: `=СЧЕТЕСЛИ(Лист1!A:A;A2)`, Фильтровать  по значениям >0, копировать, вставить на новый лист.